# how to convert $_GET and include from php to EE tags

Tags: php, get

How can i convert the following code to EE Tags?

```
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    include 'header.php';
}
?>
```

I've used this with enabling the template to PHP, but i get the following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: del

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of addons that convert `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables to EE variables. [This search might get you started](http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/get). My favorite is [Mo’ Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables), which converts them to *global variables* (of the early-parsed sort) like `{get:rel}`.

As for including, I'm not sure what your `header.php` file contains, but if it's more template code you could use an embedded template. Make a template group (say, **embeds**) and a template (**header**):

```
{if get:rel != 'tab'}
  {embed='embeds/header'}
{/if}
```

If you **do** directly include the PHP file, make sure `header.php` doesn't use `echo` as that will result in PHP errors.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to pull in GET values you should scrub it:
$this->EE->input->get('rel', TRUE);
ref http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/input.html

if ($this->EE->input->get('rel', TRUE) != 'tab'){
echo "{embed=\"site/header\"}";
}

With php parsed on input. 
If this is in a template the EE super global is already loaded. ( $this->EE =& get_instance();)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your error message says `Undefined index: del` and your code example references `$_GET['rel']` -- There's no typo at play here, is there?
2. Try this?

Set PHP to run on Input.

```
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
?>
<embed="template_group/header_template"> // With PHP enabled if you need
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the $_GET and $_POST variables (among others) are not available in templates. To accomplish something like this you could use url segments. So in you're example you may have a link like this: domain.com?rel=tab. Instead you may be able to do this: domain.com/tab. Then in your template (no PHP required) you can do this:

```
{if segment_1 == "tab"}
    {embed="site/header"}
{/if}
```

Where site/header is a template containing whatever code is in header.php. Note that the /tab could be any segment and change the conditional accordingly. I realize using segments instead of GET parameters may not always work, but this is how I have gotten around this problem myself a few times.